# How can I make Eclipse CDT auto-indent properly when using BOOST_FOREACH?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, formatting, indentation

I write this tiny C++ example in Eclipse 3.4.1 (CDT 5.0.1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int foo()
{
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  BOOST_FOREACH(int n, numbers)
  {
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << numbers.size << std::endl;
}
```

Then I hit Shift+Ctrl+F to format my code, and it becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int foo()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    BOOST_FOREACH(int n, numbers)
{   std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
std::cout << numbers.size << std::endl;
}
```

This is with the BSD/Allman Code Style. Other styles obviously vary the look of the formatted code, but none give correct indentation.

When I use the format feature on a larger piece of code, subsequent functions or methods are also affected by too little indentation, making the formatting help pretty unhelpful.

Is there something I can do to make the indentation work properly with BOOST_FOREACH?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?  The Astyle plugin is inferior IMO because it lines up function arguments way too far to the right.

Comment: I never solved this. Note that I haven't worked on this project in more recent versions of Eclipse either.

Comment: is it possible to tell eclipse that `BOOST_FOREACH` should be formatted like a `while` statement?

Comment: It's a pity that after 6 years this bug is still pending to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to some header used by your code:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
    #undef BOOST_FOREACH
    #define BOOST_FOREACH(a, b) for(a; ; )
#endif
```

Comment: Depending on how your project is set up to build (i.e. if Eclipse settings don't actually get passed to your compiler), you can also set this in "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols" in the project properties. Define a C++ symbol, "BOOST_FOREACH(a, b)" to "for(a; ; )", and allow it to re-index.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [astyle eclipse plugin](http://astyleclipse.sourceforge.net/).  It seems to be much nicer than the default eclipse style of C++ indentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is still broken in the current CDT for Kepler. But there is a bug in Eclipse's Bugzilla (check its status [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358983)). It will eventually be fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Strange, this used to work with CDT 4.  So if you really really need this I suggest you downgrade your CDT :-/

Answer (score 0):

Euh... you can't ? Try next version of CDT... :_(

Comment: I concur, comment removed. Should have read further, appologies.